Filtering output by two custom fields using posts_where and add_rewrite_rule
I'm using two custom fields in wordpress to filter a persons database (custom taxonomy = persons) by gender and age. I would like the domain path name to look like that:
domain.com/persons/women/40years/
My current code in functions.php is working, but only, if I use a single parameter name "women40years", which results in this domain path name:
domain.com/persons/women40years/
function join_test( $join ) {
    if ( preg_match( '#women40years#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as meta_1 ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = meta_1.post_id ) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as meta_2 ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = meta_2.post_id )";
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter( 'posts_join' , 'join_test' );

function where_test( $where, $query ) {
    if ( preg_match( '#women40years#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        $where .= " AND meta_1.meta_key = 'gender' AND meta_1.meta_value = 'women' AND meta_2.meta_key = 'age' AND meta_2.meta_value = 40";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'where_test', 10, 2 );

add_rewrite_rule( 'persons/women40years/?$', 'index.php?thema=persons&g=women40years', 'top' );

I guess the solution would have to do with GET parameters, pretty URL rewrite or similar, but I don't know how to handle my custom field values for that. Thank you very much in advance for your help!

What is the thema query variable used in the rewrite rule destination?

That's the name of the custom taxonomy.

I solved the problem with this code:
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "years";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

add_rewrite_rule('^persons/(women|men)/([0-9]{2})years/?$', 'index.php?thema=persons&g=$matches[1]&years=$matches[2]', 'top'); 

